# Passing array to scanf function won't work

Tags: c, arrays, printf

I'm doing C programming homework. I'm facing a problem that the variable that user key in for the scanf function always output the same thing.

```
void Update(char mCode, int mPrice)
{
 printf("Enter Code: ");
 scanf("%s",&mCode);

 printf("Enter Selling Price: ");
 scanf("%d",&mPrice);
}

int main(void)
{
....
update(stuff[i].mCode,stuff[i].mPrice);
fp = fopen("readme.txt","a+");
fprintf(fp, "%s %d\n", stuff[i].mCode, &stuff[i].mPrice);
....
return 0;
}
```

The result I got in readme.txt was **0 for the mPrice** and **blank for the mCode**.

Comment: You are passing variable by value not by reference

Answer (score 1):

Variables `mCode` and `mPrice` are local variables in function `Update`.

As such, they are only updated locally in this function.

Change it as follows:

```
void Update(char* mCode, int* mPrice)
{
    printf("Enter Code: ");
    scanf("%s",mCode);
    printf("Enter Selling Price: ");
    scanf("%d",mPrice);
}

int main(void)
{
    ....
    update(&stuff[i].mCode,&stuff[i].mPrice);
    fp = fopen("readme.txt","a+");
    fprintf(fp, "%s %d\n", stuff[i].mCode, &stuff[i].mPrice);
    ....
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not that the "array passing" do not work. You do not pass any arrays.

Note that your definition of `Update` says, you pass `mCode` and `mPrice` by *value*. This means the copies are made there and you read data into those copies (which life ends at the end of the function). You need to pass a reference to it, which in case of c is a pointer.

```
void Update(char* mCode, int* mPrice)
{
 printf("Enter Code: ");
 scanf("%s",mCode);  // just pass the pointer through to scanf now

 printf("Enter Selling Price: ");
 scanf("%d",mPrice); // just pass the pointer through to scanf now
}

int main(void)
{
....
update(&stuff[i].mCode,&stuff[i].mPrice); //pass the addresses
fp = fopen("readme.txt","a+");
fprintf(fp, "%s %d\n", stuff[i].mCode, &stuff[i].mPrice);
....
return 0;
}
```

Comment: This will at least give a warning when compiling: `mCode` and `mPrice` are pointers, you must remove the `&` in the calls to `scanf()`.

Comment: Sure. I forgot to update the body. Corrected. Thanks.